# How to determine service account used to run Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My Dataflow job fails when it tries to access a secret:

> "Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/REDACTED/secrets/REDACTED/versions/latest' (or it may not exist)."

I launch the job using `gcloud dataflow flex-template run`.  I am able to view the secret in the console.   The same code works when I run it on my laptop.  As I understand it, when I submit a job with the above command, it runs  under a service account that may have different permissions. How do I determine which service account the job runs under?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dataflow creates workers, they create instances. You can check this on Logging

- Open GCP console
- Open Logging -> Logs Explorer (make sure you are not using the "Legacy Logs Viewer")
- At the query builder type in `protoPayload.serviceName="compute.googleapis.com"`
- Click Run Query
- Expand the entry for `v1.compute_instances.create` or any other resources used by `compute.googleapis.com`
- You should be able to see the service account used for creating the instance. This service account (**boxed in red**) is used anything related to the running the dataflow job.

Take note that I tested this using the [official dataflow quick start](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default the worker nodes of dataflow run with the [compute engine default service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account) account (`YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) lacking of the "Secret Manager Secret Accessor" rights.

Either you need to add those rights to the service account or you have to [specify the service account in the pipeline options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params?hl=de#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options):

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run ... --parameters service_account_email="your-service-account-name@YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```